# How to access the properties of a nested type?

Tags: c#, types, nested, project

I have a nested type in a foreach loop:

```
foreach(var project in projectDataSet.Project)
{
    //project type = SvcProject.ProjectDataSet+ProjectRow
}
```

How can I access the `project` properties?

Comment: do you mean to do project.PropertyName?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That way it worked:

```
        foreach (var projects in projectDataSet.Project)
        {
            var project = projectDataSet as SvcProject.ProjectDataSet.ProjectRow;
            Console.WriteLine(project.PROJ_NAME);
        }
```

It seems that you should use the last entry of the nested type as you final value. I ommited an useful `null` check for brevity.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could perhaps make a model of the var project outside the foreach loop and then map the properties based on your folder directory to property variables and try calling the model from within the foreach so that you can access the model's properties which will include project.

Comment: I don't quite get what you mean, Carl. Can you be more specific, please? A little example code would be welcome as well.

For instance, using the for variation, I can read the properties like that:
                for (int i = 0; i < projectDataSet.Project.Count; i++)
                {
                    var project = projectDataSet.Project[i];
                    //Now I can do things like Console.WriteLine(project.ProjectOwnerID);
}